# Escape arguments for PDO statements?

Tags: php, pdo

New to PDO - do I need to escape arguments I'm passing into a PDO prepared statement (such as the following):

```
$_GET['name'] = "O'Brady";

$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET name = :name");
$sth->bindParam(':name', $_GET['name']);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Neither do you need any quotation marks around text strings. Just pass in the variables as they are and the MySQL driver will take care of the rest.

Comment: This also what I have been looking for

Answer (score 2):

The PDO will build the query in a safe manner so [you won't need to escape it](http://ezinearticles.com/?SQL-Injection-Protection-in-PHP-With-PDO&id=1815110).