# PDO prepare statements: Do we need to escape?

Tags: pdo, prepared-statement, escaping

```
public function receiveDomainNames($keyword)
{
  try
  {
    $stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT d.someField FROM domain d WHERE d.someField LIKE :keyword");
    $someField = '%'.$keyword.'%';
```

**Do we need to escape $keyword on this case?**

On php manual we can read:

> *If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer can
>   be sure that no SQL injection will
>   occur (**however, if other portions of
>   the query are being built up with
>   unescaped input, SQL injection is
>   still possible**).*

Is this the case on your opinion, are, on this case, build up unescaped input (no prior treatment has been made to our $keyword parameter) ?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: Actually, I'm using filter_input with FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING over our $keyword argument (before he arrives here) - So I believe no escape is necessary there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape arguments for PDO statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874636/escape-arguments-for-pdo-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the above SQL statement, I see no rational possibility of a SQL injection.

What the warning about "other parts" would be a SQL query like:

```
$binds = array(":id"=>$_GET['id']);
$myPDO->prepare("SELECT {$_GET['columns']} FROM {$_GET{['table']} WHERE id = :id");
$statement = $myPDO->execute($binds);
```

The example is a worst case/explicit example of what they mean, that naively someone might think since they're escaping the where argument, that everything is safe.

With your example above, there is no un-escaped input so you're safe.

Answer (score 0):

> If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer
>   can be sure that no SQL injection will occur (**however, if other
>   portions of the query are being built up with unescaped input, SQL
>   injection is still possible**).

I'd figure variables you create shouldn't have to be escaped because you know what they're doing.

Only escape content gotten from the user, such as $_COOKIE, $_POST, $_GET and other parameters such as the URL.