# How to strip slashes from search query

Tags: php, wordpress, search, backslash

I added the following code to the theme's index.php file on one of my WordPress sites, so that a heading would appear on the search results page that includes the actual search term. In other words, if I search for the word *blue*, this heading would then read, *Search results for: blue*.

```
<?php
if ( is_search() ); ?>
<h3>Search results for: <?php print_r($_GET['s']); ?></h3>
```

The output isn't great however when a phase in quotes get placed into the search bar. In other words, if I search for the phrase "blue is a color", this heading then reads: *Search resulst for: \"blue is a color\"*

I'd like to know how to stop those backslashes from appearing. I've done some research but nothing I've found has worked. I'm a php beginner at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use echo:

```
<?php
if ( is_search() ); ?>
<h3>Search results for: <?php echo $_GET['s']; ?></h3>
```

you must "escape" this variable before you print it though! Imagine if someone wrote a `<script>` in the search bar that manpulated your site when it was printed.  Read on here: [Escaping variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199095/escaping-variables).  One example would be like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['s']);
```

This removes characters like `<` and `>` so nobody can print scripts or html into your site

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work for me (or maybe I just don't understand it well enough). The WordPress theme developer gave me this suggestion:

`<?php if ( is_search() ); ?>
<h3 style="color: #7b5a4d"><em>Search results for: <?php print_r (stripslashes($_GET['s'])); ?></em></h3>`

Is this a good solution? It works.

Comment: @JuttaDuncan yes that is fine for removing the slashes. you should still escape the input though.  I don't know why you are getting the slashes, that must be happening somewhere else, but this will remove them just fine!

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much. I'm using this now, and that seems to work well: `<?php
if ( is_search() ); ?>
<h3>Search results for: <?php echo htmlspecialchars (stripslashes($_GET['s'])); ?></h3>`

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows you to easily be able to remove values from a String using the `explode()` command.

`$fractor = explode("\", $_GET['s']);`

You can call `$fractor` what you like, just remember that it becomes an array of all the split strings.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score -1):

Use `print` instead of `print_r`

```
<?php
if ( is_search() ); ?>
<h3>Search results for: <?php print($_GET['s']); ?></h3>
```

There is some difference in `print_r` & `print`

**print**

- Outputs only a single string
- Returns 1, so it can be used in an expression
- e.g. print "Hello"
- or, if ($expr && print "foo")

**print_r()**

- Outputs a human-readable representation of any one value
- Accepts not just strings but other types including arrays and objects, formatting them to be readable
- Useful when debugging
- May return its output as a return value (instead of echoing) if the second optional argument is given