# How to protect INSERT input from SQLi with MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code on a contact page of my site:

```
$insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `contact` (`Name`, `Email`, `Subject`, `Priority`, `DisplayName`, `Message`, `IP`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$insert->bind_param('sssisss', $_POST['name'], 
$_POST['email'],
$_POST['subject'],
$_POST['priority'],
$_POST['dispname'],
$_POST['query'],
$ip);

$insert->execute();
$newId = $insert->insert_id;
$insert->close();
```

It works fine, however, is my prepare statement enough to protect against SQLi attacks?
This is my first project since moving over from mysql_* (I know, bad of me, but now I'm making the change) and I am wondering if I am meant to escape anything else before inserting these values?

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874636/escape-arguments-for-pdo-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are pretty safe as you are using **`PreparedStatements`** and you don't have to worry about escaping as it is done automatically.

If you want to dive into detail about this. See [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582192/1003917)

Comment: @Mr.Alien, What else do you expect ?